# How to scrape embedded JSON using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping, phantomjs

I need to get a particular piece of data from a JSON string encoded within a `script` tag within a returned HTML document using phantomjs. The HTML looks basically like this:

```
... [preamble html tags etc.] 
....

<script id="ine-data" type="application/json">
    {"userData": {"account_owner": "Grib"},    
     "skey":"b207ff1f8d5a394c2f7af1681ad3470c",
     "location": "EU"
</script>

<script id="notification-data" type="application/json">
... [other stuff including html body]
```

What I need to get to is the value for `skey` within the JSON.  I am unable to use the selectors to even get to the script. For instance,

```
page.open('https://www.site1.com/dash', function(status) {
                   var ine_data = document.querySelectorAll('script').item(0);
                   console.log(ine_data); phantom.exit(); 
                 });
```

This returns `null`. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: The right direction -> http://phantomjs.org/documentation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PhantomJS function you're looking for is called `page.evaluate` ([documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)).  It allows you to run javascript sandboxed within the javascript environment of the browser itself.

So following your example:

```
page.open('https://www.site1.com/dash', function(status) {
    var ske = page.evaluate(function() {
        var json_text = document.querySelector("#ine-data").innerHTML,
            json_values = JSON.parse(json_text);
        return json_values.skey;
    });
    console.log(ske)
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Though I'd note that the JSON in your example is invalid (missing a trailing `}`), so my example won't work without fixing that first!

Comment: The JSON was a copy mistake. Thanks for the help otherwise.